# Regarding Service "CLRExtProc" in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have installed Oracle Database 11g on my desktop.
When ever I am trying to get the status of lsnrctl I am getting a message as below.

```
Services Summary...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

How to get rid of this message and what could have caused this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a listener for .NET Common Language Runtime http://www.acehints.com/2013/04/what-is-clrextproc-plsextproc-and.html.

The configuration is in listener.ora file